# Beginner Loop GUI

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

I have to make this GUI that is a CD calculator.

```
I put in the Initial investment ($): e.g. 2000
the Annual interest rate (%): e.g. (8%)
Ending value ($): e.g. 5000
```

The program then outputs on a jLabel: The amount of years required are "12" (e.g.)

I need to make a do while loop and a counter.

I did the get text from the 3 text fields then add the initialInvestment with the annual rate %  but having trouble with the loop and the counter?

```
int initialInvestment, endValue, cdvalue;
double cdValue, annualDecimalConvert, annualRate;

initialInvestment = Integer.parseInt(initialInvestmentInput.getText());
annualRate = Double.parseDouble(interestRateInput.getText())/100;
endValue = Integer.parseInt(endingValueInput.getText());

cdValue = initialInvestment + (initialInvestment * annualRate);

double a = cdValue;
while (a <= endValue){
    a = a++;
    yearsOutput.setText("The required year needed is: " + a);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are getting while implementing this. What are you expecting and what is happening?

Comment: I want it to output the amount of years it takes with a certain percent and and initial investment, The program freezes because it's and infinity loop I think.

Comment: `endValue` is with *interest + principal* or just *interest*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply adding 1 to `a` every iteration of the loop. So it'll take a few thousand iterations that way to fullfil the loop requirements.

What you have to do is keep adding the interest every year while keeping count of the years and only update the output after you're done looping.

```
int initialInvestment, endValue;
double cdValue, annualDecimalConvert, annualRate;

initialInvestment = Integer.parseInt(initialInvestmentInput.getText());
annualRate = Double.parseDouble(interestRateInput.getText())/100;
endValue = Integer.parseInt(endingValueInput.getText());

// First year interest is counted here.
cdValue = initialInvestment + (initialInvestment * annualRate);
int years = 1;

while (cdValue < endValue){
  cdValue = cdValue + (cdValue * annualRate);
  years++;
}

yearsOutput.setText("The required year needed is: " + years);
```

Comment: the yearsOutput is supposed to be ("The required year needed is: " + years);

Comment: @user3009505: Which it is?

Comment: It said     
yearsOutput.setText("The required year needed is: " + a);

Just wasn't sure, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Well, I edited it after Smit pointed the same thing out, 3 minutes before your comment. :)